# How to handle button off status while working with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Issue :

I am working with Selenium Java Web Browser Automation. The problem is when the Java code goes to the particular button for click, the button already remains in off status as a result of which that button is never clicked and thus throws an exception at every clickable link present on the web.

Here is the code I have written for the link click event. Also I have enabled element.click(). It's not working too.

```
public String click_On_Link(String locatorType, String value)
        throws InterruptedException {

    String status = "Pass";
    try {
        final By locator;
        locator = locatorValue(locatorType, value);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        //element.click(); 
        /*
         * element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER, "a")); element.click();
         */
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.err.format("No Element Found to Click" + e);
        status = "Fail" + "::" + e.getCause();

    }
    return status;
}
```

Here is the status of the button event whenever Selenium tries to reach this button :

```
<a class="t3_button_off" onmouseover="window.status='Address Information'; return true;"
```

Comment: What is the condition to make this button ON? When you say its off did you mean its not visible?

Comment: I dont think it's off. The buttons are visible all the time but when selenium tries to reach to that button, it does not click it and throws an exception

Comment: OK Perfect before you call that button include below code and run and let me know if your get assertion error ..assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("your Button name"));